# java File mkdirs and createNewFile won't work

Tags: java, file-io, ioexception, java-io, mkdirs

I'm trying to copy and existing directory structure (no need for the file contents themselves, 0 length dummy files will do). However `mkdirs()` won't create the necessary directories, causing `file.createNewFile()` to throw an `IOException`. The code is:

```
private static void readAndCopy(File fileToCopy) throws IOException {
    File localVersion = new File(fileToCopy.getCanonicalPath().replace("O:\\", "C:\\xfer\\"));
    System.out.println("Replicating " + fileToCopy.getCanonicalPath() + " to " + localVersion.getCanonicalPath());

    if (fileToCopy.isDirectory()) {
        boolean dirCreated = localVersion.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        System.out.println(localVersion.getCanonicalPath() + " " + (dirCreated ? "" : "not ") + "created");

        if (dirCreated) {
            for (File content : fileToCopy.listFiles()) {
                readAndCopy(content);
            }
        }

    } else {
        if (!localVersion.exists()) {
            localVersion.createNewFile();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    readAndCopy(new File("o:\\MY_SRC_DIR"));
}
```

The error message is:

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
```

I also tried

```
File origParentFile = fileToCopy.getParentFile();
File newParent = new File(origParentFile.getCanonicalPath().replace("O:\\", "C:\\xfer\\"));
localVersion = new File(newParent, fileToCopy.getName());
```

, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Throws what IOException? What message?

Comment: Sorry @EJP, I forgot it. Please see the updated description.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. 'mkdirs()`is creating all the directories including the file name itself as a directory. You need to call`localVersion.getParentFile().mkdirs().`

Comment: I tried it, but the symptom's the very same: directories, subdirectories not created, `createNewFile()` throws `IOException`. Not to mention that `MY_SRC_DIR` already exists under `C:\xfer`.

Comment: You mean `mkdirs()` returns true but doesn't do anything? No actual directories created on the disk?

Comment: No, mkdirs() returns false even though the parent directory already exists (was created earlier manually).